# angularJS: where is better to put signOut logic?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

in every my controller i have such code, which i execute when i click on some link in view:

```
  $scope.logout = function() {
    authenticationService.logout();
    $scope.isAuthUser = false;
    delete $localStorage.selectedModel;
    $location.path('/login').search('key', null);
  };
```

i'm new to angularJS and want to know: how is it better to do:

- to put logic in service

or

- to put logic in directive?

with directive: i know how to use controllers: `$scope.isAuth = false;` - with service: i didn't know hot to use it, except to write it as now in every controller, that it would be something like:

```
  $scope.logout = function() {
    authenticationService.logout();
    myNewService.logout();
    $scope.isAuthUser = false;
  };
```

view:

```
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-ng-click="logout()">              
      <span>Sign Out</span>
    </a>
```

but seems that it is bad too... how is it right to do?

Comment: can you provide more detail with markup, or possibly jsfiddle?

Comment: you should use nested controller and put the logout function on parent controller, no need to duplicate code in every controller

Comment: This logic has nothing to do with directives, it should be part of the service. So the only code in controller should be `$scope.logout = authenticationService.logout`.

Comment: @dfsq but where to put controllers `$scope.isAuthUser = false;` ?

Comment: Let me better post extended answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This logic has nothing to do with directives, this is for sure. You already have `authenticationService` so this is exactly the place to put business logic of the login/logout functionality. I would recommend to move this code from controller into this service.

When it's a part of the service, the only code in controller would be

```
$scope.logout = authenticationService.logout;
```

That's it. Controller should be as slim as possible and without business logic, view logic is fine, of course.

Now, regarding `$scope.isAuthUser`. `isAuthUser` sounds very much like a property of the `authenticationService` service, isn't it? After all `authenticationService` is an object which is supposed to hold methods and properties of the related model/datalayer. So again it should be moved into same service.

If you need to use this flag in templates (maybe show/hide some buttons, etc.) you could expose this service *all together* into $scope/$rootScope property. Say, in top level controller you could do something like this:

```
app.controller('mainController', ['$scope', 'authenticationService', function($scope, authenticationService) {
    $scope.auth = authenticationService;
}]);
```

and then in any template you could simply use

```
<a href="#/logout" ng-click="logout()" ng-show="auth.isAuthUser">Logout</a>
```

Comment: If you need to use this flag in templates (maybe show/hide some buttons, etc.) you could expose this service all together into $scope/$rootScope property.  - could you add simple code?

Comment: Check simple example.

Answer (score 2):

I will tell you how I do it.

- If you are executing some logic without any Ajax/API calls. Go for
  service.
- If you are calling some API - Then Factory.
- If you are working with templates/DOM-manipulation then Directive.

In particularly your case, service would be good. You can place your logout logic in service recipe.
Call that service where it is required.